# How to make a paradox-style grand strategy map with selectable provinces using bitmap?

Tags: unity

I'm in the process of designing a paradox-style grand-strategy game with a large map containing thousands of provinces. I plan on creating the map in a similar style to Paradox; by having a .bmp color file showing all of the games provinces, each with a unique RGB color and code that the game will reference when clicking on the map for the player to interact with the subsequent province.

This should give you an idea of what I'm talking about

[image: Map Example]

Each of these provinces (particularly those on land) will have their own script/text file attached to each of them that displays their current stats (such as development/population/buildings ect.) in addition, whenever the player clicks on the map, the game will check the area he clicked on and what RGB code the province he clicked on had. This will be used for a variety of the games interactions, such as moving armies and building upgrades among many other things.

Unfortunately, I'm not particularly sure how I should go about this. I have around a year of experience working in unity, but most of that is with scene/world creation and basic scripting. I've been trying to find info on how people suggest creating this sort of system, but much of it is outdated or confusing.

Can anyone here walk me through step-by-step what I'll need to do to create such a province system in Unity using C#? What else will I need to know in order to get this working?

Comment: It sounds like you have a reasonably complete plan for how to achieve this. What is the first step in executing this plan that you don't yet know how to do? Asking for a full walkthrough of the whole system is too much for our scope here, but you can ask about one concrete problem at a time. If the answers to one don't get you far enough to solve the rest on your own, you can post a second question after that, and so on.

Comment: I think my first step will be to find a way to get the game to recognize which province I've clicked on by referencing the .BMP file and seeing which RGB color I clicked on. Every color in the map is completely unique, and will have data assigned to it (such as it's name and all that.) To start things off, I'll probably need to find some way I can store values for each RGB code that the game can reference to see what province each color is assigned to. How exactly can I do that? after that, it's a matter of finding a way to get the raycast to interact with it to work properly or whatever.

Comment: So, can we simplify your question to "How can I read the picked colour on a map image"? Presumably you looked at using [Texture2D.GetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html) for this purpose? How have you tried to solve your problem so far?

Comment: Pretty much, although I'd like to find a way to store scriptable objects to specific RGB colors to hold it's specific province and all it's variables. How exactly could I do that?

Comment: I haven't had much progress done on this so far, as I've largely spent most of my time designing the game rather than developing it. I felt like I needed to ask around about a good course of action for this, as I'm not particularly knowledgeable about creating these sort of games (my previous projects were all ARPGs and FPSs iirc)

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want to create data objects for each of these zones at edit time, so you can pre-populate them with information by hand? Or do you want to generate the data objects at runtime so that there's one for every colour value in the map, with all their initial values at default?

Answer (score 0):

I'd absolutely look into getting the screenspace coords of a mouse click and using a [shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html) to get the pixel value at that location.

Also using [scriptable objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) to store information about each province is how I would do it.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: So I'd use a shader to determine the RGB code and it's respective province I clicked on, right? How could I assign a scriptable object for province data to a specific RBG code?

Comment: I would use a dictionary, you can have a key be a specific RGB value (which under the hood is just a number) and the value can be a reference to your scriptable object. Creating an editor-friendly dictionary can be a little bit of a pain but there are a couple [hacks](https://forum.unity.com/threads/finally-a-serializable-dictionary-for-unity-extracted-from-system-collections-generic.335797/) that can get around that - or just code them in script

Comment: upon looking more into it, that's exactly what I think I'll need for this. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I plan on using irregular colliders by checking the collision position on my .bmp texture and checking it's RGB code to map back to it's respective province. I'm aware of how to detect the particular color in my selection, but what should I do to have that selection reference the dictionary and find it's respective RGB color? Is there any functionality that'll allow the 2 strict to work together like that?

Comment: You mean if you have a referance and wan't to find it's RGB colour? Aside from each scriptable object holding a colour value, you could create two dictionaries, each the reverse of the other, or (if you're sure each value will be unique) you can do `var myKey = types.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == /*yourvalue*/).Key;`. Hope that's what you mean - I was a little confused by your comment...

Comment: that should work fine for me. I believe I'll be able to take the rest on myself, and I really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can describe a convex polygon shape (collection of points like Vector2) for each province. Then all you need to do is just to check whether the point where the player clicked located inside of one of that polygons.

But first, you better to calculate AABB (axis aligned bounding box) for each of your polygons. It's easy.
Then initialize two arrays with your provinces (one for x coordinate, and one for y) and sort by begin, then by the end position of corresponding axis. When user clicks on map, do binary search of the each object's AABB which overlaps with click position, then check whether this point lies inside of each of corresponding convex shape (just google it, that's easy, hint: cross product for each pair of vertices of your convex shape and vector between first vertex and the click point).

Answer (score 0):

1. Import your colour-coded map into Unity as a 2D texture.
2. Inside its import settings, tick the "Read/Write Enabled" checkbox under the "Advanced" fold-out. (This makes its pixel data accessible to CPU-side scripts)
3. Set the import format to something uncompressed - you don't want the compressor to make small changes to your colour values that might make them map to the wrong territory! Also ensure the max size setting is large enough that your texture won't be down-sampled when building the game (which can also muddy the colours)
4. Place a Quad in your scene where you want your map to appear, and scale it to the right size for your needs. By default it will have a MeshCollider on it - we'll use that to test where our mouse picking ray hits the map.
5. Create an unlit material that uses your map texture, and assign it to the quad so you can see the map features on it. This is purely for player visibility, and isn't used for the picking logic, so you can use a different image here if you want - say one with more naturalistic colours and texture detail.

Now we can pick our territory colours from this map using a simple script:

```
public class MapPicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Assign your quad's collider here.
    public MeshCollider mapShape;

    // Assign your colour-coded territory map here.
    public Texture2D colourMap;

    // We'll use this to quickly find a territory by its colour.
    Dictionary<Color32, Territory> _territoryLookup;

    private void Start() {
        // Fetch the pixel data of the texture as a big block we can iterate through quickly.
        var pixels = colourMap.GetPixels32();

        // Prep our lookup table. For efficiency, tell it how many territories you expect.
        _territoryLookup = new Dictionary<Color32, Territory>(2000);

        // Quick & dirty: we'll generate a new territory for each unique colour we find.
        // Later, you can instead populate your lookup table from ScriptableObjects if needed.
        foreach(var pixel in pixels) {
            if (_territoryLookup.ContainsKey(pixel))
                continue;

            _territoryLookup.Add(pixel, new Territory());
        }
    }

    void Update() {
        // If no click this frame, abort. Nothing to do.
        if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            return;

        // Cast a ray against the map to see if/where it hits.
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (!mapShape.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, float.PositiveInfinity))
            return;  // If we missed the map entirely, abort.

        // Map the hit point on the quad to a pixel coordinate in our texture.
        var mapSize = new Vector2(colourMap.width, colourMap.height);
        var hitPoint = Vector2Int.RoundToInt(Vector2.Scale(hit.textureCoord, mapSize));

        // Fetch the colour of the pixel we hit.
        var colour = (Color32)colourMap.GetPixel(hitPoint.x, hitPoint.y);

        // Now we can look up our territory using that colour.
        var territory = _territoryLookup[colour];

        /* TODO: do something with the territory we have clicked */
    }
}
```